# mongo java conditional sum if not null

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using the mongo java driver and trying to count all documents where a particular field is not null or does not exist. Here's what I have so far:

```
String field = "myfieldname";
BasicDBObject notNull = new BasicDBObject(field,BasicDBObject("$ne",null));
List<Object> condition = Arrays.asList(notNull,1,0);
BasicDBObject aggregation = new BasicDBObject("$cond",condition);
// boiler plate code to lookup my database/collection and pass the aggregation to it
```

This doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:
Thanks to Rob Moore, for his help. Here is what I ended up with to make it work

```
BasicDBObject ifNull = new BasicDBObject('$ifNull',Arrays.asList('$'+field,null));
BasicDBObject neq = new BasicDBObject('$ne', Arrays.asList(null,ifNull));
return new BasicDBObject('$cond', Arrays.asList(neq,1,0);
```

Comment: You are conflating two different operations.  The $cond has to be used with a $project pipeline stage.  The $sum is part of a $group stage. That can be overcome by using two stages but... You also cannot use the $exists query operator as part of the $cond expression you can only use expression operators.  Is "not exists of is null" ($ifNull) a good enough substitute?

Comment: @RobMoore Thanks. Please see my edits. I've changed it to not use exists but rather `$ne`, but I'm still having some issues, particularly with `null`

Comment: Also, I don't think `$ifNull` will work here. I want to return 1 if not null and 0 if not null OR not exists.

Comment: The field value needs to start with a '$'. I'm assuming this is then added to a larger projection?

Comment: On `$ifNull`: I was thinking you would wrap it in a `$eq` in a `$cond` to get the logic right.  Something like: '$cond' : [
          {
            '$eq' : [
              {
                '$ifNull' : [
                  '$myfieldname', 
                  ObjectId('52cb90166c4a281586e13465')
                ]
              }, 
              ObjectId('52cb90166c4a281586e13465')
            ]
          }, 
          0, 
          1
        ]

Comment: Sorry, typo on the `$myfieldname`. Let me spend a few minutes understanding your approach on `$ifNull` and see how that works. I'll post back in a little bit. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a application that implements the logic I think you are after.  It uses the [Asynchronous Java Driver's](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/) helper classes to help construct the right pipeline. At the end of the code we insert 99 total documents. 33 with a null field value, 33 with a value, and 33 without a value. The application gets a total of 66 which I think is the result you are after.

```java
/*
 *           Copyright 2013 - Allanbank Consulting, Inc.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupField.set;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupId.constantId;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationProjectFields.include;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.Find.ALL;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.cond;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.constant;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.eq;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.field;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.ifNull;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.expression.Expressions.set;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.BuilderFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.DocumentBuilder;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.element.ArrayElement;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.element.ObjectId;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.Aggregate;

/**
 * Count the number of documents that have a particular field.
 * 
 * @see <a
 *      href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964169/mongo-java-conditional-sum-if-exists">StackOverflow
 *      Question</a>
 * 
 * @copyright 2013, Allanbank Consulting, Inc., All Rights Reserved
 */
public class SumIfExists {
    /**
     * A source of no so random values. Use a fixed seed to always get the same
     * values for fields.
     */
    private final static Random random = new Random(123456789L);

    /**
     * The handle to the MongoDB client. We assume MongoDB is running on your
     * machine on the default port of 27017.
     */
    private final static MongoClient client = MongoFactory
            .createClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

    /** The collection we will be using. */
    private final static MongoCollection theCollection = client.getDatabase(
            "db").getCollection("collection");

    /**
     * Run the demo.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            Command line arguments. Ignored.
     * @throws IOException
     *             On a failure closing the MongoCLient.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build the aggregation document/command.
        Aggregate.Builder builder = Aggregate.builder();

        // From the StackOverflow Question.
        String fieldName = "myfieldname";

        // A token ObjectId to use in comparisons for the null field.
        ObjectId nullToken = new ObjectId();

        builder.project(
                include("a", "b", "c", "etc"),
                set("myfieldnameExists",
                        cond(eq(ifNull(field(fieldName), constant(nullToken)),
                                constant(nullToken)), constant(0), constant(1))));
        builder.group(constantId("a"), set("count").sum("myfieldnameExists"));

        System.out.println(new ArrayElement("$pipeline", builder.build()
                .getPipeline()));

        // Insert some documents to test with.
        theCollection.delete(ALL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i) {
            DocumentBuilder doc = BuilderFactory.start();
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                doc.addNull(fieldName);
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 1) {
                doc.add(fieldName, random.nextDouble());
            }
            // else if (i % 3 == 2) -- Field does not exist.

            doc.add("a", random.nextBoolean());
            doc.add("b", random.nextInt());
            doc.add("c", random.nextLong());
            doc.add("etc", random.nextLong());

            theCollection.insert(doc);
        }

        // Run the aggregation.
        System.out.println(theCollection.aggregate(builder));
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
'$pipeline' : [
  {
    '$project' : {
      a : 1,
      b : 1,
      c : 1,
      etc : 1,
      myfieldnameExists : {
        '$cond' : [
          {
            '$eq' : [
              {
                '$ifNull' : [
                  '$myfieldname', 
                  ObjectId('52cb94836c4a28185433c4d3')
                ]
              }, 
              ObjectId('52cb94836c4a28185433c4d3')
            ]
          }, 
          0, 
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$group' : {
      '_id' : 'a',
      count : { '$sum' : '$myfieldnameExists' }
    }
  }
]
[{
  '_id' : 'a',
  count : 66
}]
```

Am I close?
Rob.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Still working on this on my end building it into our existing pipeline - taking a little longer than I hoped. In this case I'm only looking for records where the field exists and it is not null, so I'm going after 33, but I think the point is still similar.

Comment: So I posted my edited code that works. Basically what I did was check `$ifNull`, and if that was true, then return `null`. Use that value as one side of the equals comparison against `null`.

I'm still a little confused why I couldn't just conditional with "not equal to null", but rather I had to have the `ifNull` check in there first (let me know if this is unclear)

Comment: I suspect the issue is that in BSON null is a distinct element type so null is not equal to not-exist.  The `$ifNull` (as a side effect) normalizes the not-exist and null value to the same thing.

Comment: I was thinking that, but from the mongo shell, `db.myrecords.find( { fieldname: null })` will find a record where the field doesn't exist. But you are probably right that somewhere that doesn't translate properly to the driver. Either way, appreciate the help.